# Laravel - Trying to get property text' of non-object

Tags: laravel

This is something I've done a million times before so I'm really confused as to why I'm getting this error.

In my **Controller**,  I fetch some results:

```
$modOfSubchanIDs = Auth::user()->modOf->pluck('id')->toArray();
    
$modmails = ModMail::whereIn('subchan_id', $modOfSubchanIDs)
                ->with('subchan')
                ->with('creator')
                ->with('appeal')
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                ->paginate(10);
```

then in **Blade**, I try to output the results of the following relationship:

```
@foreach ($modmails as $modmail)
<div>
    {{$modmail->appeal->text}}
</div>
@endforeach
```

Modmail **Model** relationship:

```
public function appeal()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(SubchanBanAppeal::class, 'appeal_id');
}
```

But I get the following error:

> ErrorException Trying to get property 'text' of non-object

Strange. So I try just

```
<div>
    {{$modmail->appeal}}
</div>
```

which returns the following in Blade:

> {"id":1,"subchan_id":8,"subchan_ban_id":1,"text":"test","denied":0,"created_by":5003,"created_at":"2021-03-26T00:07:58.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-26T00:07:58.000000Z"}

So now I'm really confused. Why is it returning that properly but not when I try a specific column? I also tried `{{$modmail->appeal['text']}}` but this returns

> Trying to access array offset on value of type null

It feels like I'm missing something really basic here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you do the `{{ $modmail->appeal }}` debug inside the loop? It is likely that most of the `$modmails` have an appeal, but one or two do not. If it's not the first one that is missing, your test would look right.

The `optional()` helper method can help in this scenario.

```
@foreach ($modmails as $modmail)
<div>
    {{ optional($modmail->appeal)->text }}
</div>
@endforeach
```

https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-optional

Comment: Strange. This works, but before the div I had a @if ($modmail->appeal_id) condition. That should have caught it. Oh well. Thank you!

Comment: @FelixMaxime Not necessarily. You can have an `appeal_id` that doesn't match a record in the Database (deleted or otherwise invalid). Your check should have been `@if($modmail->appeal) ... @endif`. Alertnatively, add `->has('appeal')` to your query to only return `ModMail` records that have an associated `Appeal`. There's lots of solutions for the very common error (I see it asked at least daily on Stackoverflow).